# how to find the child node element of a div "contenteditable" where the cursor is writing on input event handler

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, dom-manipulation

I am trying to create a custom textarea editor by adding contenteditable as attribute on a div element that the text will be as text element and hashtag will be as span element, but the problem is when i want to add a hashtag between text and hashtag, to do that must to find the current index of child element that the cursor is writing, and then i can use inderBefore method to add this element after this index thanks

my html code:

```
<div class="text">

   <div #textarea class="textarea" contenteditable="true" 
   (input)="onchangeText($event)" (focusin)="toggleFocus()" (focusout)="toggleFocus()" >

       that is a post <span class="hashtag">#hashtag</span> try to add hashtag at the 
       <span class="hashtag">#beginig</span> will be add as last child to the and

   </div>

   <div class="placeholder" *ngIf="checkPlaceHolder()" (click)="onclickPlaceHolder($event)" 
    [ngStyle]="{opacity:focus? 0.5 : 1}">

       What do you want to share?

   </div>

</div>
```

here is my input event handler:

```
onchangeText(event) {
   // on input event handler

   if (this.isAfterHashtag()) {
      this.onAddElement(event.data, "text"); //add new element
   }

   if (this.isHashtag(event.data)) {
     // if character is # hashtag

     this.onAddElement(event.data, "hash");
   }

   this.setText();

   if (this.checkPlaceHolder()) {// if the length of textare is 0

     this.textarea.nativeElement.innerHTML = "";
   }
}
```

here is my addElementMethod:

```
onAddElement(text, type) {

   this.removeLastCharacter();

   if (type === "hash") {
      // add element for hash tag
      const span: HTMLParagraphElement = this.renderer.createElement("span");
      span.innerHTML = text;
      this.renderer.addClass(span, "hashtag");
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.textarea.nativeElement, span); 
     //must use insertBefore method, but before it must find index of child elemenet where to add it
     // this.renderer.insertBefore( this.textarea.nativeElement , p , this.textarea.nativeElement.children[1] );
   } else if (type === "text") {
      // add element for text
      const textNode = this.renderer.createText("");
      textNode.textContent = text;
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.textarea.nativeElement, textNode);
   }

   this.setText();

   this.setCursorToEnd();
}
```

here is an example:

[custom textarea editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ezq1bm?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)