# Selecting element of an contenteditable div when Enter Key is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

I want to get the element where the event occured. This snippet only logs the parent element
eg. .
How to log the current element where the key is being pressed
eg. 1st or 2nd

```js
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keypress', event => {
console.clear();              
console.log(event.target)})
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="text" contenteditable="true">
        <div>1st</div>
        <div>2nd</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you try making the first and second div `contenteditable`?

Comment: you can clearly see i didn't contenteditable is applied to the parent.

Comment: Yes. I meant: try to make the inner divs contenteditable. That should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried to question to simplify my question. I should have been more clear. I want to get the nth-child of the parent. when I create a contenteditable div and write to it the browser it creates div element, assuming the browser is chrome. Making the child element contenteditable will also create child element of the contenteditable childs. I want to know where the cursor is at any given time like when the user press 'enter'.i have recently found similar question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325570/how-to-find-the-child-node-element-of-a-div-contenteditable-where-the-cursor-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: This should do the trick:

```
<div id="text" contenteditable="true">
    <div>1st</div>
    <div>2nd</div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keypress', function(ev) {
      var selection = window.getSelection();
      var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      var container = range.commonAncestorContainer;
      var nodeParent = container.parentNode;
      console.log(nodeParent);
});
</script>
```

It checks the current selection (the text that is selected by the cursor from start to beginning). In your case, i.e. at `keypress`, the selection will be the same from start the end, being the actual position of the cursor.

The `Selection` can contain multiple ranges (all kinds of nodes, including text nodes), depending on what the user selected on the page. Here we are only interested in the first one, where the cursor is, so we do `getRangeAt(0)`.

It then looks at the common ancestor container, being the text that is currently being edited. The `commonAncestorContainer` is the node in which the `Range` is situated. In this case it is either the text node with the text "1st" or the text node with the text "2nd".

Now that we have the Text Node that contains the first `Range` of the current `Selection`, we can see its `parentNode`, being the current div.

Does that do the trick?

Comment: Thanks it worked fine but I want a different approach. contenteditable should be applied to the #text div not it's child elements. when i start to write script it should be able to add an attribute to it's child. i think my question is answered partially here.

Comment: Update my answer

Comment: Yes! this is what i was looking for. It still lacks caret movement detection. I don't know if I should mark it as answer but I really want to.

Comment: Caret movement can be done with the same Selection and Range objects as in my answer. It just takes some effort to get to know all these. What do you need to accomplish? You never mentioned caret movement...

Comment: That's why I marked this as the answer. I just wanted to know how it works and understand it.